# ASP .NET Gridview Dashboard - Custom Formatting Based on Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm looking for a dashboard using asp.NET grid which should display the sales of products in a year. If the sale count is between 1- 1000 it should display a red alert image and if 1000 -5000 it should display a yellow alert image and > 5000 should show up 
green alert inside the grid cells.

Please let me know the easiest way to accomplish this functionality using three alert images (red, Green, Yellow)

Comment: This is your friend http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

See Scott Mitchell's tutorial on [gridview](/questions/tagged/gridview) databinding in [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581771.aspx, specifially section 12: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288031.aspx

You'll want to use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to control the rendering of the sales:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Image id="RedAlertImage" Visible='(Eval("Sales") as int) < 1000' />
         <asp:Image id="YellowAlertImage" 
                Visible='((Eval("Sales") as int) > 1000) && ((Eval("Sales") as int) < 5000' />
         <asp:Image id="GreenAlertImage" Visible='(Eval("Sales") as int) > 5000' />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Sales" />
```